# polymer serve reformats files

Tags: visual-studio-code, polymer

I am developing an application with Polymer 1.8.0. While trying to remote debug in Chrome from VSCode I noticed that the line numbers in the Chrome source view did not match with the line numbers in VSCode and henceforth debugging did not work at all.

After some testing I realized that `polymer serve` seems to reformat the files, e.g. the source file (line break with LF, indention with spaces)

```
<link rel="import"
      href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
```

would be delivered as

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
```

with no line break at all.

My first guess was that the recompilation feature for ES6 was to blame and I disabled it with `polymer server --compile never` but with no success.

I am using Mint 19, Polymer 1.8.0, Chrome 70, VSCode 1.28.1

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known bug, see here: https://github.com/Polymer/tools/issues/389